# Angular 2 + Spring : Getting NULL as a fetched data at server side from client side

Tags: java, spring, typescript, angular2-services

I am developing an application using angular 2 at client side and spring at server side.
I want to send user entered data from client to server and get appropriate response from server.
Steps that I am executing:
1. Enter the details in the form and press submit button.
2. On submit through service data should be passed to server for validation however at server side I am getting null value for 'loginDetailsDTO'.

Please help me to get the data at server side.

Thanks in Advance.

Below is the sample code:

**user.component.ts**

```
 import { UserService } from './user.service';
 import { UserLogin } from './userLogin';

 login( value: UserLogin ) {
     this.UserService.login( value )
         .subscribe( data => console.log( data ) );
 }
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { UserLogin } from './userLogin';

login(loginDetails: UserLogin) {
    return this.http
        .get(this.loginUrl,JSON.stringify(loginDetails))
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

**userLogin.ts**

```
export class UserLogin {
    userName: string;
    password: string;
}
```

**userController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login",method = RequestMethod.GET
@ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> login(LoginDetailsDTO loginDetailsDTO){

        LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
        loginResponse.setResponseCode(LoginResponse.VALID_USER);

        return new ResponseEntity<LoginResponse>(loginResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**LoginDetailsDTO.java**

```
public class LoginDetailsDTO {

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using POST request to send login data to the backend.
Here:

```
login(loginDetails: UserLogin) {
      return this.http
      .POST(this.loginUrl,JSON.stringify(loginDetails))
     .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And on the backend write your controller as follows:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = urlPattern , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody LoginDetailsDTO) {
        //magic
    }
```

Also note that `/login` POST request are handled by spring as a default, I believe it is a much better practice to define your own login url for example `/authenticate`

Comment: Thank you @balag3. I have modified code as per your suggestion. Now I am getting below error:  
'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8095/authenticate. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403'

Comment: Do you use Spring security as well? Because then you have to define your
login url as .loginprocessingUrl('/authenticate') in spring security config chain.

Comment: No. I am not using spring security.